# How do I search words separated by spaces in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, text-editor

So I can search a word in Vim using /. However, it only searches for one word. For example, if I search "Stack Overflow", it only searches for "Stack". How can I ask Vim to search the whole "Stack Overflow"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though you need to escape certain characters to prevent them from being interpreted as regular expression atoms (which can be reduced by prepending the `\V` "very nomagic" atom; then, only backslashes need to be escaped), **whitespace does not need escaping**. Therefore, it should be possible to search (starting from normal mode) simply via `/Stack Overflow`, and concluding with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If that doesn't work for you, a plugin or custom configuration has corrupted your Vim.

Answer (score 8):

Use backslash `\` before space in search string.

To search for **"Stack Overflow"** use `"Stack\ Overflow"` in command mode.

Comment: If the accepted answer does not work for you, this answer works